# Create tube from two edges

Tags: workflow, vertices, edges

I have two edges that represent the top and bottom parts of a tube:

[image: cylinder]

I would like to be able to create a tube from that which fills in the rest of the data automatically, interpolating between the two on the up/down axis so that the sides are properly merged at the halfway point.

[image: cylinder2]

Here's an example of what the finished product should look like, created manually.

In other words, a script (or clever set of built in functions) that would:

- walk through each top and bottom pair of vertices
- create two cylinders from them on the XY axis, using the distance between the vertices as the diameter of the cylinder
- interpolate between the two cylinders using the Z axis as a weight to create the final geometry

In the case of mismatched vertex pairs, I don't mind fixing them up manually so that quads can be nicely generated from them; it's the rest of the steps that would otherwise involve a huge amount of manual labor as these objects can be thousands of vertices long. I also looked at using NURBs curves instead of edges, but am not familiar enough with NURBs to know if what I'm looking for can be done with them.

Does something like this exist? If not, what is the most efficient pipeline to create models from this type of input data?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean to do, couldd you post an example image of what you want to achieve?. From my current understanding, the word you might be looking for is *lofting*. Look into the [BSurfaces add](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) which allows doing that using curve guides. NURBs are indeed the correct geometry type for this sort of thing, though Blender's NURBs tools are severely lacking and inappropriate for production use.

Comment: I've added a 2nd picture to clarify that. I'll take a closer look at NURBs in the meantime, but further guidance in using them to accomplish this goal would be appreciated if it is indeed the optimal choice.

Comment: how is your input data coming in? how are you generating these sets of polylines in the first place? the two polylines don't have matching vertex counts..

Comment: You only need one edge to use the [spin tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html), you could also use a [screw modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html)

Comment: Blender NURBS probably won't help much in this case, maybe something like [MoI](http://moi3d.com/) but it is a commercial application. As far as I know Blender has limited built in native tools for this sort of geometry, nothing adequate for lofting. Your best bet is really probably the BSurfaces Addon mentioned above. I'll try to think of something else in the meantime and post it here if I get anywhere.